# Overloading template operator*

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

```
// vec2.h
template<class v_float=float>
class vec2
{
public:
    v_float m[2];
};

template<class v_float>
vec2<v_float> operator* (v_float & f, vec2<v_float> & v);

template<class v_float>
vec2<v_float> vec2<v_float>::operator* (v_float & f, vec2 & v)
{
    return vec2(v.m[0]*f, v.m[1]*f);
}
```

I want to overload the operator* for the above template class vec2, but the above code gave me the following error: vec2.cpp:68: error: 'vec2 vec2::operator*(v_float&, vec2&)' must take either zero or one argument

How to overload the operator*(float, vec2) for a template class? note that the number of parameters of operator* must be two.

Comment: The number of parameters for operators is one less when they are implemented as members functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in this template member function:

```
template<class v_float>
    vec2<v_float> vec2<v_float>::operator* (v_float & f, vec2 & v)
{
    return vec2(v.m[0]*f, v.m[1]*f);
}
```

Since you're defining `operator *` as a member function here, C++ automatically assumes that the receiver object is one of the operands.  This means that if you want to define multiplication, you should only be defining a function that takes one argument, namely, the right-hand side of the multiplication (since the left-hand side will be the receiver object).

I think you meant to have this as a free function, as shown here:

```
template<class v_float>
    vec2<v_float> operator* (v_float & f, vec2<v_float> & v)
{
    return vec2(v.m[0]*f, v.m[1]*f);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have used a constructor that was not declared and overloaded * with a member function and also a non-member function.  Best practice is generally to use a non-member friend function.

Something like this:

```
template<typename v_float=float>
class vec2
{
    v_float m[2];

public:
    vec2(const v_float &f1, const v_float &f2) { m[0] = f1; m[1] = f2; }

    template<typename T, typename Y>
    friend vec2<Y> operator*(T f, const vec2<Y> & v);
};

template <typename T, typename v_float>
vec2<v_float> operator*(T f, const vec2<v_float> & v)
{
    return vec2<v_float>(v.m[0]*f, v.m[1]*f);
}
```